# Fetching value from a number column removes 0 before decimal

Tags: sql, oracle, nls

There is a number column in database. When it is fetched as char using TO_CHAR then the digit before decimal point is lost.

`Select TO_CHAR(column) from table`

For e.g. 0.5 is stored in the column but when selected it returns .5

Similarly if -0.5 is stored then -.5 is returned .

What could be the reasons for this ?

Is it related to NLS setting ?If yes which setting should be changed to retrieve the value as it is stored .

Comment: Leading zeros are not stored in the database.  Numbers are stored using internal formats.  If you want the leading zero, then use `to_char(col, '0.0')`.

Comment: @PTK storage and display are two different things. Use the `dump()` function to see how it's really stored. It's not `'-0.5'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
select to_char(.5,'0.000000')from dual
```

That's not an NLS issue.  NLS changed things like decimal separator, thousands separator, etc.
Not sure how many decimals needed after the decimal point, so you can change that.  I would also look at the [number format models doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Comment: The column is NUMBER so precision will vary. How to find out number of zero's to be added in TO_CHAR after and before  decimal point

Comment: There is never more than one zero prior to a decimal point.